# Adjustable custom UI

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-constraintlayout

I have a custom view made up of 3 elements.
I want the view to be adaptive to the size available to it.
I want it to look like [image: this].

But to get it to look like this I had to add hard coded size constraints thus making it none adaptive.

This is how it looks using match_constraint on all image views (not the way I want it to look like [image: this]):

And here is the xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="in.avimarine.boatangels.activities.InspectionResultActivity"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/moored_boat_bowlines"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:contentDescription="@string/boat_drawing_content_description"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/moored_boat_body"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/moored_boat_body"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/moored_boat_body"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_monohull_mooring_bow"
      tools:visibility="visible"/>
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/moored_boat_body"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:contentDescription="@string/boat_drawing_content_description"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/moored_boat_sternlines"
      app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/moored_boat_bowlines"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_top_mv"
      tools:visibility="visible"/>
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/moored_boat_sternlines"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:contentDescription="@string/boat_drawing_content_description"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/moored_boat_body"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/moored_boat_body"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/moored_boat_body"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_monohull_dock_aft"
      tools:visibility="visible"/>

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</merge>
```

How do I make this adaptive and still look like the first image?

Comment: use can use relativelayout  instead.

Comment: @Reyansh Mishra, can you give an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a custom adaptive view using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html). Please notice the *layout_constraintVertical_weight* attribute.

**boat.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/moored_boat_bowlines"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bowlines"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/moored_boat_body"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/moored_boat_body"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/body"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/moored_boat_sternlines"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/moored_boat_bowlines"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="10" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/moored_boat_sternlines"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sternlines"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/moored_boat_body"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then you can use it in any other layout.

**activity_one.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#8493"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Filled!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/boat" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

**activity_two.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/boat_view"
        layout="@layout/boat"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ConstraintLayout you can use [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/first" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sec"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/first"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/sec" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sec"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/third" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Images not aligned properly because I have not sized them perfectly.]

Answer (score 1):

I got a way to make this work. Include  `android.support.constraint.Guideline`

Now you can arrange all the three elements center in screen and one below the other as shown.

As the images I used are small, it looks small and attached to top of screen. But in your case this will look as expected. All the images are using both `height` and `width` as `wrap_content`

### To align top and center of screen

[image]

Below is the xml for the same

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".02"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".98"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        android:id="@+id/iconOne"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iconTwo"
        android:src="@drawable/contactus"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iconOne"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iconThree"
        android:src="@drawable/pricelist"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iconTwo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### To align center to the screen

Now if you want these three images to center of screen , then below approach will be good.

[image]

Corresponding xml will be

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".02"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".98"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        android:id="@+id/iconOne"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/iconTwo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iconTwo"
        android:src="@drawable/contactus"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iconThree"
        android:src="@drawable/pricelist"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iconTwo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

These samples will give us a good start for ConstraintLayout

[Reference One](http://www.uwanttolearn.com/android/constraint-layout-concepts-hell-tips-tricks-part-2/) , [Reference Two](https://medium.com/@loutry/guide-to-constraintlayout-407cd87bc013) and [Reference Three](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Linearlayout` for this issue and you could set weight for each image so that it aligns properly and it will fill fit all screen sizes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/top_image"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:padding="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
         android:src="@drawable/middle_image"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bottom_image"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

feel free to edit

```
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
android:src="@drawable/bottom_image"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: Tried it, and I can't understand how weight is supposed to help here

Comment: by adjusting the weight you could set the height percentage of the image view and it will adjust itself depending upon the screen size @CaptainNemo